# How to start a Slide Show without using the Slide Show palette

Tags: slideshows

Is there a way to start a presentation or Slide Show Mode without having to load the Classic Slide Show palette?  Once the presentation starts there's a Close button to end the Slide Show Mode but I can't find the Start button in the notebook or in the menu.  Alternatively, if I had to create a button to do so.  What would be the command to start the Slide Show Mode?

Comment: How do you want it to work? If there are no slides, how can it be a slideshow?

Comment: I never said what you understood. I do have a notebook with the slides. I need to start the Slide Show Mode without using the Classic Slide Show Palette.

Comment: What version are you using? I've only ever clicked the button up at the top to start the slide show, which appears when I change to the slideshow stylesheet.

Comment: Definitely picking the stylesheet solves the problem.  Interesting that by converting a notebook to a presentation using the "Slide Show from Current Notebook" button in the Slide Show palette didn't do that for me.  Many thanks!

Comment: maybe you can find a way to peel out the code that makes up the start slide show functionality?